# If $X_n$ has a Binomial Distribution $B(n,p)$, why is it true that $X_n = np + O_p(\sqrt{n})$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

If $X_n$ has a Binomial Distribution $B(n,p)$, why is it true that $X_n = np + O_p(\sqrt{n})$?

I saw this as an example inside a textbook but the textbook had a very strange argument as follows:

**"We know that $E(X_n) = np$, $Var(X_n) = np(1-p)$. Hence, $\sigma_n = \sqrt{np(1-p)} = O\left(\sqrt{n}\right)$. Then, we may conclude that:
$$
X_n-np = O_p\left(\sqrt{n}\right)"
$$**

Here is what confuses me: It is a well know statement that if $X_n$ is a stochastic sequence with $\mu_n = E(X_n)$ and $\sigma^2_n = Var(X_n) < \infty$, then:

$$
X_n - \mu_n = O_p(\sigma_n)
$$

By using this theorem, we get:

$$
X_n - np = O_p\left(\sqrt{np(1-p)}\right)
$$

Why do the results differ in $\sqrt{p(1-p)}$ inside the big-oh in probability? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $p$ is fixed, so $O(\sqrt{np(1-p)}) = O(\sqrt{n}\sqrt{p(1-p)}) = O(\sqrt{n})$ (as $\sqrt{p(1-p)}$ is just some constant).